# Spark Structured Streaming not running continuously?

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

Server code:

```
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.Random;

public class Socket_server {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ServerSocket sc = new ServerSocket(9990);
        while (true) {
            Socket socket = sc.accept();
            java.io.OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();

            String message = getRandomIntegerBetweenRange(100, 120) + "";
            byte b[] = message.getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset());

            out.write(b);
            out.close();
            socket.close();
        }
    }

    private static double getRandomIntegerBetweenRange(double max, double min) {
        double x = (int) (Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1)) + min;

        return x;
    }
}
```

Spark code:

```
import java.util.Collections;

import org.apache.avro.ipc.specific.Person;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.MapFunction;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQuery;
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.Trigger;

import scala.Function1;

public class App1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
        conf.setMaster("local[*]");
        conf.setAppName("app");

        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().config(conf).getOrCreate();
        Dataset<Row> lines = spark.readStream().format("socket").option("host", "localhost").option("port", 9990)
                .load();

        StreamingQuery query = lines.writeStream().format("console").start();

        query.awaitTermination();
    }
}
```

I am running server code which is generating random values and after that i am running spark Structured Streaming code to read it and create DataFrame from it. But as my spark code start it just read the first value from the server after that it does not read any further value.When i am using this same server with spark streaming then that is reading values continuously. So can anyone help in what is wrong with code.

Comment: I _think_ that `Socket_server` is incorrect (in `while` loop) where you open and close a different socket that _somehow_ is not the one Spark uses. Put Spark aside and use another client, e.g. netcat, to check out the behaviour.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski But when i am writing normal spark streaming this same code of socket server is working.